# Importing a file with LESS won't see the @filename var

Tags: less, syntax-error, string-concatenation

I'm trying to load an `.less` file into my main theme, this is my filestructure:

```
main.less
themes/pink.less
themes/yellow.less
themes/blue.less
```

I'm using this `mixin` to retrieve the selected theme:

```
.theme(@filename){
    @import 'themes/@{filename}.less';
}

.theme('pink');
```

It doesn't work and I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: variable @filename is undefined
.theme('pink');
```

I'm used to do the same with background images without getting errors, where I'm wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/410)

Comment: The link in your comment is "old" in that if you are running version 1.4 it should work, assuming you are not externally defining the variables (i.e. importing the variables to be used in the `@import`), as that is [apparently not yet supported](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1359) (all imports start without waiting for other imports to have loaded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Less.js throws the error you describe with imports for `.less` files (it works fine with imports for `.css` files), if you define the variable in in the mixin parameter/attribute, but it works if you define the variable directly inside (localy) or outside the mixin (globaly). For example, this should work:

```
@filename: 'pink';

.theme(){
    @import 'themes/@{filename}.less';
}

.theme();
```

[Here is a link to a discussion where the plan of implementing this has been discussed a while ago](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/410#issuecomment-13825920), and it seems that the longterm goal is to have your version working as well, it just hasn't happened yet completely ^_^

However, if you just want to load a theme according to the variable, you can do it without the mixin. just by doing something like this:

```
@theme: 'pink';
@import 'themes/@{theme}.less';
```

Comment: Thanks for the infos, I was trying to avoid that way but for now it will be fine!